# Combination questions

Tags: combinatorics

Q: A team of $11$ is to be chosen out of $15$ cricketers of whom $5$ are bowlers and $2$ others are wicket keepers. In how many ways can this be done so that the team contains at least $4$ bowlers and at least $1$ wicket keeper?

Answer (score 2):

The number of ways to choose exactly $4$ bowlers and exactly $1$ keeper:

$$\binom{5}{4}\cdot\binom{2}{1}\cdot\binom{15-5-2}{11-4-1}=280$$

The number of ways to choose exactly $5$ bowlers and exactly $1$ keeper:

$$\binom{5}{5}\cdot\binom{2}{1}\cdot\binom{15-5-2}{11-5-1}=112$$

The number of ways to choose exactly $4$ bowlers and exactly $2$ keepers:

$$\binom{5}{4}\cdot\binom{2}{2}\cdot\binom{15-5-2}{11-4-2}=280$$

The number of ways to choose exactly $5$ bowlers and exactly $2$ keepers:

$$\binom{5}{5}\cdot\binom{2}{2}\cdot\binom{15-5-2}{11-5-2}=70$$

The number of ways to choose at least $4$ bowlers and at least $1$ keeper:

$$280+112+280+70=742$$

Comment: @zonnie: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\binom{5}{4}\binom{2}{1}\binom{8}{6}+\binom{5}{5}\binom{2}{1}\binom{8}{5}+\binom{5}{4}\binom{2}{2}\binom{8}{5}+\binom{5}{5}\binom{2}{2}\binom{8}{4}$$

Comment: Thank you idm.. I have solved it the same way you did.. but in my book, answer is 350. while solving with above four combinations answer is 742. means in book 1st and last combinations are taken. 2nd and 3rd discarded. Means wrongly done?

Comment: I am almost sure of my answer... but it's not impossible that I'm wrong. Moreover, **Back2Basic** has the same answer than me... so maybe your book gave a wrong answer... We'll see a futur comment to confirm or not the result :-)

Comment: Yeah same thing as i get the concept of combination. I was sure about my answer. Thank you for confirming. May be its wrong in book. Thank you idm & Back2Basic.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Bowlers: $5$

Keepers: $2$

Others:  $8$

$A = A_{41} + A_{51} + A_{42} + A_{52}$

$A_{41} = \binom{5}{4}\binom{2}{1}\binom{8}{6}$

$A_{51} = \binom{5}{5}\binom{2}{1}\binom{8}{5}$, etc..